# Canvas J2mE list form

Tags: forms, canvas, java-me, midp, lcdui

How can I create create a form/list using canvas and add TextField to it?

```
public void paint(Graphics g){
g.setColor(44,255,44);
 g.fillRect(0,0, getWidth (), getHeight ());
form = new Form("");
form.append("acfascca");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

See this article [Drawing TextField on Canvas j2me.](http://textfieldcanvasj2me.blogspot.com/) But i feel If you are starting new project means you can go with [LWUIT Framework.](http://lwuit.java.net/) Also see this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6152237/what-is-lwuit-light-weight-user-interface-toolkit/6165904#6165904).

Answer (score 0):

Canvas is a low level API, hence I don't think it supports adding of Form to it.